# Why does this question not allow me to make a simple tag edit?

Tags: support, bug

Just come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23536597/692942) which is clearly [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) not [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) but it won't let me remove the tag without editing the body of the post, I do this all the time why is this question any different?

> Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

This doesn't usually appear when I make a tag edit what am I doing differently?

The process is;

1. Click edit link in question.
2. Removed [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) and replaced with [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net).
3. Added reason *"Removed asp-classic as this is a .net question"*.
4. Click `Save Edits` button and the validation message above is shown.

Comment: There is an *edit tags* link hidden to the right of the existing tags. It will allow you to change only the tags, without touching the question body and without a character limit (I did that for you in that question). It might be linked to the 2K edit privileges though, so maybe you cannot see it yet.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thanks for editing it but I don't see what link you are referring to? What I also find strange is I do this all the time using the steps above, but I'm not usually prompted to make edits to the body.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That's a [10k privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: This doesn't explain why it was requesting I edit the body usually modifying tags is fine as long as the body is left untouched. Anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have sufficient reputation to have editing privileges (without review).

Small suggested edits are discouraged.  Suggested edits not only consume the editor's time, but also the time of several reviewers.  We therefore require that suggested edits be more substantial than a simple tag change or single spelling fix.

When you gain editing privileges, you will be able to make such edits unilaterally.

Comment: So was the minimum 6 char limit recently added to tag only edits; they used to be an exception to that limitation.  (Not that I have a problem with it, I just didn't see an announcement for it.)

Comment: @Servy I also thought this was the case. I've done this before and it has never asked me to edit the question body.

Comment: I have no idea.  But the outcome is going to be the same: earn 2000 rep, and you won't have to worry about the trivial edit trigger.

Comment: Tag edits are important especially when trying to filter through the rubbish in [tag:asp-classic] only to find it's a [tag:asp.net] question. Whenever I come across this scenario I edit the tag (only edit the body if there is something substantial to change) and I have not encountered this issue until now.