# Remove [readutf]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Currently the [readutf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readutf) tag only has two questions and I question its usefulness in relation to the more general and popular [utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/utf-8).

The only reason I'm asking here before simply removing it from one (seems unrelated) and retagging the other is because, in one of them, it was added in an edit by a user with 106k rep.  Since I'm (comparatively) a noob here, I want to make sure I'm following proper procedure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, it would have been okay to remove. (I think your edits would have gone into the review queue anyways, though I’m not entirely sure how the retagging privileges work now.)

Comment: Retagging is simply treated as an standard edit, in my experience. So yes, they would go into the queue as suggested edits.

Comment: @JWLim: There was a time when retags skipped the queue at about half the reputation level of the General Editing Privilege, but I don’t see it on the privilege list now.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that. No, there currently isn't such a privilege on the list. It seems to be [a rather recent change](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253996), though I don't recall ever seeing that privilege since I joined.