# Old suggested edit on edited question looks like vandalism

Tags: bug

I just came across [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6905354), which is presented by SO as if the author intended to replace "template" by "tempalte", by replacing valid C++ identifiers by invalid C++ identifiers, by replacing comments by syntax errors, and by adding a tag. I voted to reject it as vandalism.

After that, I saw that [the question had been edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28250809/revisions), presumably after the edit suggestion had been made, and the edit suggestion would probably have been fine.

As I understand it, spam/vandalism is treated harshly, so I'm not happy with the way the system presents this, where innocent edit suggestions can be misinterpreted as vandalism.

Shouldn't edit suggestions be discarded if someone manages to squeeze in an edit without doing anything about a pending edit suggestion? Or am I wrong in thinking that rejecting this as vandalism will count against the suggestion's author?

Comment: I know I've seen this issue before... I don't know if there was any resolution for it though.

Comment: @HansPassant That's not what happened, though. When I saw the edit suggestion, the question had already been edited to spell "template" correctly, to name the function "non_template", etc. The left side accurately reflects what the question looked like at the time I voted to reject the suggestion. I didn't tag it as a bug because I wasn't sure if it counts against the suggestion's author, and if it doesn't, it's only minor. Perhaps I should, though, minor bugs are still bugs.

Comment: That's actually still an invalid edit (although not spam or vandalism), because it substantively changes the code.

Comment: It should be noted that the few edits from this user that I've looked at also seem to be destructive, for example placing '.htaccess' as `code`. They also seem to be making edits without improving the actual quality of the post, and in my opinion this behaviour should be concerning. Look at their [reputation changes](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3952604/manoj-gopi?tab=reputation), they seem to be 'repwhoring'.

Comment: @dfeuer: The only thing in that edit was a tag addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking closer, I think the system is working confusingly but correctly.

The edit was made on 2015-01-31 11:03:47Z.

The edit suggestion was made on 2015-01-31 11:03:49Z, two seconds *after* the edit.

Now, I can completely understand the user not having seen that the question had already been edited, when submitting the suggestion. The user started to edit the question, someone else snuck in a different edit, the user submitted the edit suggestion based on the old question text.

However, there was a large gap between the moment the edit suggestion was made, and the moment it was rejected. That was plenty of time for the user to fix the edit suggestion, and the user should have done so.

Answer (score -1):

It should be noted that the few edits from this user that I've looked at also seem to be destructive, for example placing '.htaccess' as `code`.

They also seem to be making edits without improving the actual quality of the post, and in my opinion this behaviour should be concerning.

Look at their [reputation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3952604/manoj-gopi?tab=reputation), they seem to be 'repwhoring'. It's good to see a user actively suggesting edits, but the edits from this user are *low quality* or should be expanded, for example:

- [SQL query assistance](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28249902/revisions)- Question has no mention of MySQL, therefore the [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) should've been edited *out*;
- [how to make thread-safe row matrix in java](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28249858/revisions)- Post has other issues such as spelling errors and unnecessary content (such as `tnx`). This edit should've really been a `Reject and Edit` or rejected outright;
- [How to Call Webservice with Ksoap in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28249343/revisions)- Same issue as with the previous edit suggestion;
- [I am getting frindlist data null from facebook after login.Can any check it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28249238/revisions)- Yet again, the same issue.

The edits of this user could see a little bit of refinement, especially in the case that there are *other* things wrong with the post that the user didn't correct.

As seen [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253996/why-does-this-question-not-allow-me-to-make-a-simple-tag-edit), small edits such as editing tags are frowned upon:

> Small suggested edits are discouraged. Suggested edits not only
>   consume the editor's time, but also the time of several reviewers. We
>   therefore require that suggested edits be more substantial than a
>   simple tag change or single spelling fix.

As for your question:

> Shouldn't edit suggestions be discarded if someone manages to squeeze in an edit without doing anything about a pending edit suggestion?

Yes, you're the 1%; you can squish the suggested edits of puny peasant users such as myself.
I recall reading that if a post has a suggested edit pending and the edit is overridden by a user with the privileges to apply edits straight away, Community steps in to cast a moderator reject vote so that the pending edit suggestion is squashed and the user's edit is immediately applied.

Comment: I disagree with you on the first edit you found: the mysql tag is perfectly appropriate, as long as it's added by the author of the question (and it was). SQL questions are very rarely about ANSI SQL (which is not even implemented by the major SQL DB implementations). Answers there should keep in mind any MySQL idiosyncrasies. As for the others, "Too minor" is no longer a valid reason for rejecting an edit suggestion (though I wish it were). If an edit suggestion is correct, it should be approved, even if there are other remaining issues with the question.

Comment: I do agree that the user in question could probably make better edit suggestions, though. As for the last part of your answer, if that had happened, there wouldn't have been a problem, I wouldn't even have seen the edit suggestion as it would've been rejected already. Do you have any thoughts on why it might not have happened?

Comment: @hvd May have been a bug.

Comment: It'll be nice if the downvoters add their thoughts to why they disagree with me.

Answer (score -22):

People with higher reputation points can discard or reject edits and that should take away some reputation points from that possible spammer/vandal.

Comment: There was no vandal, that's the whole point. It looks like there was, but there wasn't. As for rejecting edits, I know that's possible, I did so, and mentioned doing so in my question here.

Comment: so you mean you ask is it good to reject edit you don't like?

Comment: if yes and it looks spammy one just reject it

Comment: @Deimantas it sounds like you have no clue what this question is about.